# Arabic Stemmer using ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

is there an efficient Arabic stemmer using ruby?

Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't know what an arabic stemmer is, but sounds interesting.

Comment: stemming is the process for reducing inflected (or sometimes derived) words to their stem, base or root form (wikipedia).
for example, when you have a word like 'player', you get the root 'play', this helps you when performing some statistics over a document.

but i need an Arabic Stemmer so i can parse arabic documents :D

Answer (score 0):

I checked the [ruby-stemmer](https://github.com/aurelian/ruby-stemmer), and it doesn't look like it has Arabic, but looking at the [Snowball project](http://snowball.tartarus.org/) which the gem uses, you might want to email their list. I clicked a couple, and looking at the [Hungrarian stemmer](http://snowball.tartarus.org/algorithms/hungarian/stemmer.html), it doesn't look too bad. I wonder how difficult it would be for a native Arabic speaker to follow the example of one of the other languages and try and contribute an Arabic stemmer to the project. I assume hooking up the `ruby-stemmer` gem would be trivial if the stemmer file for Arabic was already in there. Or another route might be looking for an Arabic stemmer file and asking for help to get it into the Snowball project.